# How to create an android library from a package on eclipse?

Tags: android, jar, android-library, android-package-managers

I did not find any information about how to create my own library from a package that I made. For example, my project contains 3 packages (A, B, C), but I only want to create an library using  the package C. How can I do this? Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Just put your C package in a different project and export it as a jar file.

Comment: My project uses OpenCV and its is already  configured. Do I really have to this? And if I create a new project the export the jar file, will OpenCV be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new project with particular package and mark it as a library project and just build project and a jar for will be generated in your bin folder.